# An eigen value problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let  $A$ be a  $3×3$ matrix with $\operatorname{trace} (A)  = 3$ and  $\det (A) = 2$. If $1$ is an eigenvalue  of $A$, then what are the eigenvalues of the matrix  $A^2 - 2I$?

Comment: How to handle the trace and det: the [properties of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Further_properties).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Can you find the other eigenvalues of $A$ ? what do you know about the sum of all eigenvalues of $A$ ? what about their product ?

Comment: No, Sir, I don't know, How to find other Eigen Values.I know that the sum of the eigenvalus is equal to trace and their multiplication is equal to the determinant.

Comment: then if the eigenvalues are $a,b,1$ you have $a+b+1=3,ab=2$. can you solve for $a,b$ ?

Comment: yes, Sir, a = 1 +- (i.root3)/2....

Comment: @ram, that isn't the answer. Here's a hint: $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$

Answer (score 2):

Once you have determined the eigenvalues of $A$, observe that they are distinct, hemce $A$ is diagonalizable (at least over $\mathbb C$), hence the eigenvalues of $A^2-2I$ are just the values $\lambda^2-2$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, that is $-1$, $a^2-2$, $b^2-2$ with the values found e.g. with Belgi's hint.